# How do I calculate and return the value of pointer to max element? C++

Tags: c++

I'm Having extreme difficulties with this question. Here is what i have coded, but it wont work. These are the instructions.
TO DO: Insert code here to calculate and return
value of pointer to max element (first one if ties.)

```
Node * pointerToMax(LinkedList *list) {
assert(list!=NULL);
assert(list->head != NULL);

Node *max = list->head;

for (list->head=list->head; list!=NULL; list->head=list->head->next){
    if (list->head->next > max){
        max = list->head->next;
    }
}
return max;
}
```

Comment: note that list->head->next is a pointer , max is a pointer too. You just compare two pointers.

Comment: @Angel Garcia How nodes have to be compared to find the amximum?

Comment: Is there a value being stored in each Node?

Comment: @Ron Tang  I might be wrong, but doesnt my if stament compare the list->head->next with max?

Comment: @samgak so do i have to change my first line to "int max = list->head->data?"

Comment: see Vlad from Moscow's answer - you use the data member variable for the comparison

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the nodes are compared by their data member `data` (or by data member `value` or some other data member, you did not show how the nodes have to be compared). Then the code can look like

```
Node * pointerToMax( LinkedList *list ) 
{
    //assert(list!=NULL);
    //assert(list->head != NULL);

    if ( list == NULL || list->head == NULL ) return NULL;

    Node *max = list->head;

    for ( Node *node = list->head->next; node !=NULL; node = node->next )
    {
        if ( max->data < node->data ) max = node;
    }

    return max;
}
```

If the class Node defined `operator <` that is used for comparison of nodes then you should substitute statement

```
        if ( max->data < node->data ) max = node;
```

for

```
        if ( *max < *node ) max = node;
```

Comment: Is a random node created for the first part in the for loop ( Node *node = list->head->next )? Is Node *node the next element in the LinkedList?